# Visual studio not recognizing Xamarin.Forms project structure/syntax

Tags: visual-studio-2013, compiler-errors, syntax-error, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin and downloaded a few sample Xamarin.Forms projects such as [this](http://developer.xamarin.com/samples/XAMLSamples/) to learn. However, every project I downloaded and opened is full of  errors like the one shown in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kYZS.jpg). My problem is that although my Visual Studio 2013 displays a ton of errors and warning, I can still run these projects just fine on the emulators (I tried both android and windows phone).

Is there some way to fix my visual studio so that syntax/compiler error messages won't show up?

Comment: are you using a shared project here or PCL?

Comment: The projects that I downloaded were all PCL I think.